# SQL Distinct Values?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need your help with a query, I've looked around but can not find what I need.

Here's my table.

```
items   status  range
item1   A   1
item1   A   2
item1   A   15
item1   A   38
item1   A   451
item1   A   110
item1   A   112
item2   A   38
item2   A   451
item3   A   1
item3   A   2
item3   A   110
item3   A   112
item3   A   120
item4   A   451
item5   A   451
item5   A   110
item5   A   112
item6   A   110
item6   A   111
item6   A   115
```

Here is the intended result:

```
items   result
item1   common
item2   conv
item3   common
item4   conv
item5   ms
item6   ms
```

Here's the conditions:

```
range 38 or/and 451 - CONV
range between 110 and 115 - MS
others - Common
```

Thank you!!

Comment: have u tried anything so far?

Comment: This can be achieved by using CASE function.

Comment: yes, i've tried tge CASE function. but it wont give the result i need.

Comment: I need to know what items are exclusive by 'CONV' and 'MS'. the others are 'Common'. e.g. Item1 is common and item2 is exclusive CONV

Comment: Do you want to sum the range values for each item-no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT  sel.items
,       CASE
            WHEN COUNT(1) = 1 THEN MAX(sel.textRange)
            ELSE 'Common'
        END AS Result
FROM    (
            SELECT  DISTINCT T.items
            ,       CASE 
                        WHEN range in (38,451) THEN 'CONV' 
                        WHEN range >=110 and range <=115 THEN 'MS' 
                        ELSE 'Common' 
                    END AS textRange
            FROM    Your_Table AS T
        ) sel
GROUP BY sel.items
```

Result (tested in sql server, but should work for Oracle):

```
+-------+--------+
| items | Result |
+-------+--------+
| item1 | Common |
| item2 | CONV   |
| item3 | Common |
| item4 | CONV   |
| item5 | Common |
| item6 | MS     |
+-------+--------+
```

(I think the result for item5 is incorrect in your sample output.)

Comment: Thank, works as intended!
(yes, item5 is a 'Common')

Answer (score 2):

Try this...if you find any syntax errors while executing let me know... will update the answer..

```
 WITH Some_CTE (Items, Result)  
AS  
(  
    select items ,case 
    when range in (38,451) then 'CONV' 
    when range >110 and range <115 then 'MS' 
    else 'Common' end as Result from yourtable )  
SELECT distinct items,Result 
FROM Some_CTE where result=(select top 1 range from Some_CTE order by result desc) ;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code doesn't return the result i need, this code repeats the items in several lines. 
I need the distinct items and the resutl

Comment: this gives me:
2004635 CONV
2004635 Common
2779629 CONV
2779629 Common
2779629 MS

Comment: square brackets are invalid in an SQL identifier. And `go` is not a valid SQL statement either

Comment: How can syntax that is not valid Oracle SQL be accepted as the answer?

Comment: Not just invalid Oracle SQL, this answer is invalid in any dialect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like so:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 'item1' items, 'A' status, 1 RANGE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'item1' items, 'A' status, 2 RANGE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'item1' items, 'A' status, 15 RANGE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'item1' items, 'A' status, 38 RANGE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'item1' items, 'A' status, 451 RANGE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'item1' items, 'A' status, 110 RANGE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'item1' items, 'A' status, 112 RANGE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'item2' items, 'A' status, 38 RANGE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'item2' items, 'A' status, 451 RANGE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'item3' items, 'A' status, 1 RANGE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'item3' items, 'A' status, 2 RANGE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'item3' items, 'A' status, 110 RANGE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'item3' items, 'A' status, 112 RANGE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'item3' items, 'A' status, 120 RANGE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'item4' items, 'A' status, 451 RANGE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'item5' items, 'A' status, 451 RANGE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'item5' items, 'A' status, 110 RANGE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'item5' items, 'A' status, 112 RANGE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'item6' items, 'A' status, 110 RANGE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'item6' items, 'A' status, 111 RANGE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'item6' items, 'A' status, 115 RANGE FROM dual)
SELECT items,
       CASE WHEN MAX(common_present) = 'Y' THEN 'common'
            WHEN MAX(ms_present) = 'Y' THEN 'ms'
            WHEN MAX(conv_present) = 'Y' THEN 'conv'
       END RESULT
FROM   (SELECT items,
               status,
               RANGE,
               CASE WHEN RANGE IN (38, 451) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END conv_present,
               CASE WHEN RANGE BETWEEN 110 AND 115 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ms_present,
               CASE WHEN RANGE NOT IN (38, 451) AND RANGE NOT BETWEEN 110 AND 115 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END common_present
        FROM   (your_table))
GROUP BY items
ORDER BY items;

ITEMS RESULT
----- ------
item1 common
item2 conv
item3 common
item4 conv
item5 ms
item6 ms
```

This works by first determining which category or categories each row falls into (a Y if it does otherwise an N), and then finding out the highest value in each category ('Y' is greater than 'N') for each item.

Then it's just a matter of working out what to display as the result - having values outside of 38, 451 and 110-115 means the item is common, etc.

The only case this doesn't cover is what to do if the range value could be null. I have assumed that it can't be null, but if it could be null, you'd need to tell us what you'd expect to have happen in that case (would it end up in common?).